# Apex Trigger to run lead assignment rules not working when update

Tags: apex

I created an APEX trigger to re-assign leads following certain changes to their fields. The trigger only applies to Leads that were assigned to a Queue and not to a User (See code below)

The trigger works correctly when leads are updated manually, and also when updated from the API. But if the lead is updated by a workflow, the Lead Assignment Rules to not run and the Lead remains assigned to the Queue.

Is there anything wrong in the trigger?

```
trigger RunLeadAassignmentRules on Lead (after update) {
    List<Lead> ls = new List<Lead>();

    for (Lead l : trigger.new) {
        Lead old_lead = trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id);
        // Only run if the lead was assigned to a Queue and not
        // A person. We do not reassign if you are assigned already.
        if ( old_lead.OwnerId.getSobjectType() == Group.SObjectType &&
             (
               old_lead.State != l.State ||
               old_lead.Country != l.Country
             )
            ) {
            ls.add(new Lead(id = l.id));
        }
    }

    if (ls.size() > 0) {
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
        Database.update(ls, dmo);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Ariel

Comment: May it have something to do with the fact that it's "after update" and not "before update"? Is there a difference in the way after update triggers work when the update comes from a Workflow?

Comment: Update: Chaging the Trigger to before update didn't fix the issue. Although it's probably a better way to do this anyway. So question still relevant Thanks!

Comment: I know i am a bit late but we call also use the Process builder and call an apex call from there after we meet the criteria.I am a newbie to salesforce so please  correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, and wanted to share the solution with you.
When an "after update" trigger runs in the context of a Workflow, you must run reassignment rules after the whole workflow ended In order to allow the Lead Assignment rules to see the Lead after the transaction of the Workflow ended.

This is the code to achieve this (By Adding an async call to the reassignment rules):

```
trigger RunLeadAassignmentRules on Lead (after update) {

    Set<ID> ls = new Set<ID>();

    for (Lead l : trigger.new) {
        Lead old_lead = trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id);
        System.Debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,l.OwnerId);
        System.Debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,old_lead.OwnerId);

        System.Debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,l.Status);
        System.Debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG,old_lead.Status);

        // Only run if the lead was assigned to a Queue and not
        // A person. We do not reassign.
        if ( old_lead.OwnerId.getSobjectType() == Group.SObjectType &&
             (
               old_lead.Number_of_Employees__c != l.Number_of_Employees__c ||
               old_lead.State != l.State ||
               old_lead.Country != l.Country
             )
            )
        {
            ls.add(l.Id);
        }
    }

    if (ls.size() > 0) {
        // This is the Fix
        ReassignLeads.futureLeadReassign(ls);
    }
}
```

And this is the Async Apex Class

```
 public with sharing class ReassignLeads {
    @future
    public static void futureLeadReassign(Set<ID> lIdReassignSet) {

      List<Lead> lUpdList = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id IN: lIdReassignSet];
      for (Lead l:lUpdList){
        Database.DMLOptions dmo = new Database.DMLOptions();
        dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule  = true;
        l.setOptions(dmo);
      }

      update(lUpdList);
    }
}
```

Remember that tests written for this trigger must use Test.startTest(); and Test.stopTest(); in order to wait for the async calls to finish before checking the results of the test.

Answer (score 0):

I think the workflow trigger your code . maynot reassign because of it will cause a loop again.

Salesforce may have some policy .So if you write a trigger that i suggest you move all workflow to trigger to collect all logic in the same place . And easy to debug

Comment: Thanks,I am not sure that Salesforce would have a way to assume that my trigger would cause a loop. The Workflow fills the Country field based on some simple logic on other fields, and is not related to the goal of this trigger, I would not mix the two. Thanks!